# creating hyperloglog in mongodb

Tags: sql, mongodb, hyperloglog

I am trying to write hyperloglog in mongodb. What is equivalent version of query (written in oracle) in mongodb

```
create table my_hll as
select mod(ora_hash(n), 1024) bucket,
max(num_zeroes(trunc(ora_hash(n)/1024)))+1 val
from previous_data
group by mod(ora_hash(n), 1024);
```

Comment: [so] is not a code conversion service. Show us what your have tried and explain where your are stuck. Don't just post SQL and expect somebody to write the query for you

Comment: I have not asked directly, how to write a hyperloglog in mongodb, instead I have written simple sql, and looking for help to  convert function like mod(ora_hash(n), 1024) bucket,
max(num_zeroes(trunc(ora_hash(n)/1024)))+1 in mongo. Please read properly.